# passing id to ajax using jqueryajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I only know how to pass an id when using `href`,but using ajax is `url:xxx.php`.

So I dunno how to pass and id to ajax and how to receive it.

```
var grid = $("#employee_grid").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    rowSelect: true,
    post: function ()
    {
        /* To accumulate custom parameter with the request object */
        return 
        {
            id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
        };
    },

    url: "responseX.php?id=<?php echo $some_data ?>",//I know this row were wrong,please told me answer if you know

    formatters: 
        {
            "commands": function(column, row)
            {
                return "<a href=\"cus_details.php?id="+row.TICKET_ID+"&tgrp="+ row.AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID+" \"><button data-row-id=\"" + row.TICKET_ID + "\">Details</button></a>";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: where is the jquery ajax you mention?

Comment: Im not so sure this is jquery ajax or not,but everyone call this jquery ajax

Comment: I would think jquery ajax looks like `$.ajax(...)` or `jQuery.ajax(...)` - but your only jQuery method is `bootgrid` - that's not regular jQuery method - what other jQuery plugins are you using?

Comment: im only using bootgrid,no other plugin

Comment: You probably need to enable server-side ajax because default is false. What are you expect or what errors you get?

Comment: I want to pass some data to another page call respondX.php

Comment: but I cannot just using `url = responseX.php?id=...` to pass it.So I want to know what is the actual way to pass some data to another page and how to get data on the other page